# Is there a way to display the real time clock in a UEFI menu?

Tags: c, system, clock, uefi

I want to display a real-time clock in [YY/MM/DD, hh:mm:ss, time zone] format. How do we do the real-time update at each second on the page?

I am new to UEFI. I am referring to a page in which we press F2 or Esc to reach a menu when we boot a computer. In that menu, we can check the CPU temperature, configure IP address, etc in different pages. Here is an example,
https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/NetworkPkg/Ip4Dxe/Ip4Config2Nv.c

Let's say I am looking at this Ip4Dxe page in the UEFI menu and I want to add a real-time clock on the first line of the page.

To fetch the time, I use `gRT->getTime(&Time, NULL)`. I can then display the Time variable on the page. However, I have no idea how to make it update automatically in real-time. Do we have some RuntimeServices to support this?

Comment: What's a UEFI menu page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Look at the BootServices functions CreateEvent and SetTimer.